# Prevent jQuery Tabs to bind to <ul> elements below the main <ul> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Link

Link

Filter by something

Filter by something

Filter by something

And I set it to a tabbed control:

```
$('#mytabs').tabs();
```

My problem is jQuery UI also converts the <li> elements in <ul id="filter-controls"> into tabs. Is there a way to instruct jQuery UI to only set the <li> children of <ul id="main-tabs"> as the tabs?

Note: I am currently in no position to change <ul id="filter-controls"> into a non-ul element.

Comment: is `<ul id="filter-controls">` and its contents really needed to be there in the first place?

Comment: yes they have to. The designer's already added lots of visual elements in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a hacky solution. I removed <ul id="filter-controls"> and inserted it back after calling tabs()